# How to remove dot from \subsection* in Appendix

Tags: sectioning, amsart

I am using the AMS Article LaTeX template and when I need my Section and Subsections to not have numbering before them (since they are part of the Appendix), I use the '*' and type;

```
\subsection*{A. Additional Figures \& Diagrams}\hspace*{\fill} \\
```

However, what I see is that LaTeX adds an unesessary dot at the end of the subsection, as highlighted in red in the image below,

[image]

All the similar questions here relate to how to get rid of the unnecessary dot in the example below by changing...

1.1. Subsection B

to...

1.1 Subsection B

However, I actually need to change...

1.1. Subsection B.

to...

Subsection B

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: There is a command `\nopunct` that can be added at the end of headings normally defined with a period, to omit the period.  This was provided not for the use you cite, but to avoid a period when the heading text ends with a different punctuation symbol, such as a question mark or exclamation point.  (That said, I would define additional sectioning commands that also break the line after the heading, but are otherwise patterned on the existing `\section` and `\subsection`, which can be found in the document class.)

Comment: Hi Barbara,
Sounds like you are the right person to answer this with your background at AMS. I tried \nopunct but found LaTeX complaining; "You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode."
I have a MWE at
filebin.net/fjiauhlweg97pm5o
Hans

Answer (score 2):

The `amsart` document class is programmed to insert a "dot" (aka "period" of "full stop") at the end of *all* sectioning headers below the section level -- and not just in the appendix, but throughout the entire document.

My working assumption is that if you want the dot removed from unnumbered subsection-level headers in the appendix, you will also want to have the dots removed from all other sectioning headers, throughout the entire document.

If this assumption is correct, you can achieve your formatting objective by adding the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{%
   \ignorespaces#8\unskip\@addpunct.}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip}{}{}
\makeatother
```

I will leave it to your imagination to determine what `\@addpunct.` does. :-)

Comment: Hi Mico,

Thank you so much for your prompt response.
I tried your advice, but I couldn't get any combination of it to work :(
So, I attach in the original post "MWE.tex" and "amsart.cls".
I think with your experience, we should be able to find a solution soon.

Regards,

Hans

Comment: @HansSchmidt - Did you post `mwe.tex` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry. Try,
https://filebin.net/fjiauhlweg97pm5o