# Remove dot at the end of subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, punctuation, ieeetran

I am using `IEEEtran` (with the `conference` option). I would like to remove a period at the end of the title.

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

This example results:

```
1. Section
1.1. Subsection
1.1.1. Subsubsection.
```

How I can remove the period after `\subsubsection`?

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500807/how-to-remove-dot-from-subsection-in-appendix

Comment: Are you sure that you want to manually change the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason behind this stems from the difference between how `\section` and `\subsection` is set when compared to `\subsubsection`. The former two use a  *display* style, while the latter uses a run-in style. In order to separate the sectional unit title/header from being too close to the content, [`IEEEtran`](//ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) mentions this in the [class file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls):

```
% TITLING OF SECTIONS
\def\@IEEEsectpunct{:\ \,}  % Punctuation after run-in section heading  (headings which are
                            % part of the paragraphs), need little bit more than a single space
                            % spacing from section number to title
% compsoc conferences use regular period/space punctuation
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\ifCLASSOPTIONconference
\def\@IEEEsectpunct{.\ }
\fi\fi
```

You can update `\@IEEEsectpunct` for "lower level headings" to just be (say) a space:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@IEEEsectpunct}{~}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
This is a display section.

\subsection{Subsection}
This is a display subsection.

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
This is a run-in subsubsection.

\end{document}
```

Note that changing class styles for an article that will be submitted for print is not advised, since the journal will remove any special modifications anyway.